# Gray cargo prop plane with ∇ or Δ symbol on side and French-like tricolor flag tail?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What type of plane flown today has the following characteristics?

- gray body
- cargo/freight
- 4 props
- ∇ or Δ symbol on side
- vertical, French-like tricolor flag on tail's rudder

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Can you give us any more information for context, especially where and when you saw the aircraft?

Comment: The two possibilities I know of are the C-130 and the A400M. I suspect the latter as shown in this linked [photo](https://www.planespotters.net/photo/657413/f-rbad-arme-de-lair-french-air-force-airbus-a400m-180).

Comment: @Gerry Perhaps. I'm not claiming the plane is French. Also, the 3, French-like tricolor (blue, white, red) stripes were vertical on the rudder only, but perhaps these planes have various paint jobs.

Comment: When and where was the aircraft observed?

Comment: @CptReynolds Yesterday, landing in a civil airport.

Comment: @Geremia Well. Which one? At least the country would give a clue, if you don’t want to share actual location... but it would even be better knowing which airport it was!

Comment: Did it have a conventional tail (suggesting C-130) or a T-tail (suggesting A400M)?

Comment: @Sean I don't recall the tail.